# Match Everything from Set, except one character

Tags: regex

Let say I have set of characters `[a-z]`.
I want to match every character from the set, except "a".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can specify the [character ranges](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) as you want, for example:

```
[b-z]
```

This will only match the character from `b` to `z`. The only restriction is that it’s a valid character range according to the character set that is used so that the first character has a lower code point than the second character.

Comment: Hi ! I figured that [b-z] is simplest solution. But what if I would want something in the middle of alphabet ? [a-df-z] for letter except "e". I am looking for something direct.

Comment: @user465292: That is the most comprehensive way. Another way would be to use [look-around assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), e.g. `(?!e)[a-z]` (look-ahead) or `[a-z](?<!e)` (look-behind). But those are not supported by every regular expression library.

Answer (score 11):

```
[a-z-[e]]
```

means "any character between a and z except e". But as far as I know, only .NET, JGSoft and XML Schema support these "[subtracted character classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/xmlcharclass.html)".

Another example:

```
[a-z-[aeiou]]
```

matches any (ASCII) consonant.

Comment: In Java, those would be `[a-z&&[^e]]` and  `[a-z&&[^aeiou]]`; in a character class, `&&` is a set intersection operator.  Supposedly Oniguruma (Ruby 1.9+, TextMate) supports `&&` too, but I'm not in a position to test it.

Answer (score 3):

Complete solution (i.e. no matter where the character is located in the [a-z] set *and* much more compatible):

```
[^\W\dA-Z && x]
```

Where "x" is the character (or group of characters, e.g. efgh) you want to exclude.

Tested on:

http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html

http://regexpal.com/